# How to have a horizontally aligned table output in Flextable package in R

Tags: r, flextable

Although, there are similar questions posted on the web, my question is specifically related to the shape of the output table which is produced by using the `Flextable` package in `R`. More specifically, the following code

```
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)

set_flextable_defaults(font.size = 14, theme_fun = theme_vanilla,
                       background.color = "#EFEFEF", fonts_ignore=TRUE)


flextable(mtcars) %>%
  print(preview = "pdf")
```

produces this pdf output, which is a table vertically aligned. However, I would like to have a horizontally aligned table.

[image]

In other words, I want the horizontal page layout, something like the following table. And my question is, how can I get that pdf output, having a horizontal layout, by using the `Flextable` package in `R`.

[image]

Comment: Do 'horizontally aligned table' means 'centered table'??

Comment: Not actually. In other words, what I mean by 'horizontally aligned table' is the table that has the horizontal layout. For instance, in the first picture, the table is vertically aligned, at least that's how I refer to it. However, in the second picture, it is more like horizontally aligned and that's what I want to produce as a pdf output.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand. Maybe you want only floating placement in the PDF document, in that case, refer to https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/set_table_properties.html and search for `opts_pdf`